# number of ways to make $2.00

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different ways can you make $2.00 using only 1 cent, 5 cent, 10 cent, and 25 cent pieces, and 1 and 2 dollar bills (there are 100 cents in a dollar)? I have worked out an equation:

$$p + 5n + 10d + 25q + 100l + 200t = 200$$

Where all variables are non-negative integers. But I don't know what to do from here to figure out how many different sets of non-negative integers there are that satisfy this equation. What do I do next?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2). Scroll down in the link to the counting change example.

Comment: It will probably make you less crazy to count, starting from 200 (1 way), to 100 + 100 (2nd way), to various partionings of one of the 100s, then the distinct partitionings of both 100s, rather than to try to find integer solutions of a single six-variable equation.  (It really won't take that long to do.)

Comment: Check this site, I think it will be usefull http://www.maa.org/features/mathchat/mathchat_4_19_01.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive algorithm for general monetary systems:

Let $f(x;a_0,a_1...a_k)$ be the number of ways to make $x$c with coins/notes of value $a_i$.

$f(200;1,5,10,25,100,200)=1+f(200;1,5,10,25,100)$

$f(200;1,5,10,25,100)=1+f(100;1,5,10,25)+f(200;1,5,10,25)$

$f(200;1,5,10,25)=1+f(25;1,5,10)+...+f(200;1,5,10)$

Carry on like this, using $f(0;...)=1$ and

$f(x;a_0..a_k)=1+f(a_k;...a_{k-1})+...+ f(na_k;...a_{k-1})$

where $n$ is the greatest integer such that $na_k \leq x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions.
All you have to do is find the coefficient of $x^{200}$ in the formula
$$
(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)(1 + x^5 + x^{10} + \cdots)(1 + x^{10} + x^{20} + \cdots)
$$
$$
\cdot (1 + x^{25} + x^{50} + \cdots)(1 + x^{100} + x^{200} + \cdots)(1 + x^{200} + x^{400} + \cdots)
$$

The problem is inherently quite computation-heavy, but reducing it to the question above makes the computation much more straightforward, and also very easy to do with a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $~2729~$ ways.

Answered with the help of a computer program made by me.

Comment: That is correct, but only if we include half dollars (which, according to the question, it doesn’t appear we are).  If we exclude silver dollars, it appears we’d get an answer of 1707.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the coin changing problem popularized by Pólya in his "On Picture-Writing", AMM 63(10), 689-697 (dec 1956). Graham, Knuth and Patashnik's "Concrete Mathematics" develops a closed form solution.