# How many different ways to combine $2?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Suppose there are these coins: 1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, \$1 (100c) and \$2 (200c). How many different ways can \$2 be made using any number of coins?

I figure we need to use generating functions, so let $C(x)$ be the generating function:
$$ C(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^{5})(1-x^{10})(1-x^{25})(1-x^{100})(1-x^{200})} $$

How to compute (like an algorithm) the coefficient of $ x^{200} $?

This question is similar to 
[number of ways to make $2.00](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397502/number-of-ways-to-make-2-00) but no computing the solution there.

Comment: Just because no answers are satisfactory there doesn't mean that you should post the same question again. Once you get enough reputation on the site, you can comment there to ask the answerers for clarification, or post a bounty on the question.

Comment: The "duplicate" only asks for how many. I am unsure, but it seems this one is asking how to find solutions (or a function to do so, I should say.)

Comment: I am asking a different question. Specifically how to compute the coefficient, as in perhaps an algorithm.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{200}$ is $1707$.

Comment: And how did you get 1707, Mhenni?